# Trouble with LI tags stacking when inline

Tags: html, css

This works fine until I introduce the `<br>` tag and another line of content. The inline `<li>` tags end up stacking.

```html
<ul style="list-style:none;">
    <li style="display:inline;border:1px solid red;">
    C
    <br>A
    </li>
    <li style="display:inline;border:1px solid red;">
    B
    <br>D
    </li>
    <li style="display:inline;border:1px solid red;">
    A
    <br>E
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear (to me) what you'd like this to look like.  It seems to be doing what you've asked it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the list items on one line, and rest on a second line, you could try floating them with :

```
li {
    float: left;
}
```

[JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ke67gj12/1/)